# Extract name from TextField and divide by letters

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

Here again to ask for help from anyone who can help me.

In a nutshell, what I want to do is: when I click on the button, extract the name entered in the textfield, separate the letters and with Page View show the image (which is in the firebase) corresponding to each letter.

I'll leave the images of everything I find useful so that someone can help me.
I tried using a Custom Action but it didn't work, maybe I'm using it wrong.
Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmLjc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Qnl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwqeY.png

If you need more information to help me, please ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the name to a list and use it in a loop like the following

```
String name = 'kaushik';
var list = name.split('').map((char) => char).toList();
print(list);

///Output
///[k, a, u, s, h, i, k]
```

Then create a map of alphabets and path to each image and you can use that for example

```
 Map<String, String> imgPath = {
      'a':'imgpathfora.jpg',
      'b':'imgPathForB.jpg'
    };
};
```

now you can render it like this

```
PageView(
          children: List.generate(
              list.length,
              (int index) =>
                  Image.network(imgPath[list[index]]!)),
        )
```

Comment: yeah, and how do I show the image corresponding to each letter in the PageView?

Comment: i don't if you noticed but i'm working with FlutterFlow

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are wanting to:

1. Extract a name/letter from a TextField widget
2. Separate the name into it's individual letters and map the letters to an image
3. Use a PageView widget to display the images which are stored in a Firestore collection

Here is what I did to accomplish what I believe you are looking for.

### Page Updates

I have a local page state variable `letterImages` which I use to generate the children images of the PageView widget.

#### Local Page State

[image: page state variable]

#### PageView Setup

[image: PageView setup]

### Action Flow

I set up the following action flow for the button:

[image: action flow]

1. Queries the `letters` collection for all documents

[image: query letters]

2. Updates the `letterImages` local state variable with the `getImages()` custom function which takes the input from the `TextEntry` widget and the action output `allLetterDocs` list of `letters` documents as input:

[image: custom function]

Here is the custom function and a short description of what it is doing:

```dart
List<String> getImages(
  String inputStr,
  List<LettersRecord> letterDocs,
) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  List<String> images = [];
  List<String> characters = inputStr.toLowerCase().split('');

  for (var character in characters) {
    for (var doc in letterDocs) {
      if (doc.letter == character) {
        images.add(doc.imageUrl);
        break; // Found the matching letter, no need to keep looking.
      }
    }
  }

  return images;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

The custom function splits the word into characters, loops through each character, connects the character to a document in the `letters` Firestore collection based on the `letter` field (a field you didn't previously have), extracts the URL from the `image_url` field and appends it to a new list, and then returns the list of ImagePaths.

### Firestore Schema

You will need to add the `letter` field to each of your Firestore documents so the custom function will work:

[image: firestore schema]

### Result

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMzeSNgaFig) is a video showing the app in action.